# Select comma by comma keywords with REGEX

Tags: regex

Hello folks I have a line like that in my file.

```sh
> **Keywords** : test, test2, test3
```

And I need to select keyword by keyword and all array with regex.
NOTE: That test elements can be more than 3

```sh
Group 1 : test, test2, test3
Group 2 : test
Group 3 : test2
Group 4 : test3
```

I try to write that regex but it's not repeated for all commas :(

```regex
/^(> \*\*Keywords\*\* : ),?([\w]+)/gmi
```

This is the test env : https://regex101.com/r/UHLrX1/2

How can I handle that regex?

Comment: Is it Jvascript or PHP?

Comment: If you have only 3 keywords, you can write manually 3 groups in your regex. If the number of keywords is variable, first remove the `> **Keywords** : ` part and then split by comma and space (`, `).

Comment: doesn't matter I just need regex. But if you curious about that I will use with js

Comment: In general, the programming language **does matter**, because the regex syntax (or expressiveness) may vary according to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, you may use this regex with a lookbehind assertion:

```sh
(?<=(^> \*\*Keywords\*\* : )(?:\w+, )*)(\w+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UHLrX1/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=`: Start positive lookbehind

  - `(^> \*\*Keywords\*\* : )`: Match `> \*\*Keywords\*\* :`  and capture it in group #1
  - `(?:\w+, )*`: Followed by 0 or more comma separated words
- `)`: End positive lookbehind
- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ character word in capture group #2

Comment: Thank you anubhava. But what is the reason use \*\*Keywords\*\* twice in regex. Can we handle with ones.

Comment: Hey also I need a group like "test, test2, test3" all in one how can  I do that

Comment: and also in this version, it's grouping for every match I think it didn't has to be!

Comment: You can get either `test, test2, test3` in separate groups or in one single group. Otherwise don't use a single regex solution and do it 2 step. 1. To check for start of line and 2. to get all comma separated words in the matching line.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to capture more than 3 elements as per shown samples then one could try following regex:

```
^\*\*Keywords\*\*.*?:\s+((?:(?:[^,]*),\s+){1,}(?:.*))$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/jvRYgk/1)

---

---

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^\*\*Keywords\*\*.*?:\s+(([^,]*),\s+([^,]*),\s+(.*))$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/09kQRb/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^^\*\*Keywords\*\*.*?:\s+     ##From starting of value matching till colon followed by spaces(1 or more occurrences)
(            ##Starting 1st capturing group here.
  ([^,]*)    ##In 2nd capturing group matching everything till comma comes.
  ,\s+       ##Matching comma followed by spaces 1 or more occurrences.
  ([^,]*)    ##In 3rd capturing group matching everything till comma comes.
  ,\s+       ##Matching comma followed by spaces 1 or more occurrences.
  (.*)       ##In 4th capturing group matching everything till comma comes.
)$           ##Closing 1st capturing group till end of value.
```

Comment: I want to start with specific this line "**Keywords**" How can I Implement here

Comment: @HasanTezcan, I have edited regex now, thank you.

Comment: hey thank you for editing but it is not handled after 3 keyword if I want to add more keyword it will not work

Comment: @HasanTezcan, could you please try following once `^\*\*Keywords\*\*.*?:\s+((?:(?:[^,]*),\s+){1,}(?:.*))$` once you confirm I will update my solution then.